# Laravel 5.4 SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found (but the column exists!)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

This is a very weird error, maybe I am overlooking something: I am running this query:

```
    $getUnsupportedOS = Nessus::select('nessus_tags.unsupported_os')
        ->where('nessus_tags.unsupported_os', '=', 'true')
        ->join('nessus_tags','nessus_results.tagID','=','nessus_tags.tagID')
        ->whereRaw('nessus_results.scan_end >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP((NOW() - INTERVAL '.'1'.' MONTH))')
        ->count();
```

But it is giving me this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'nessus_tags.unsupported_os' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `nessus_results` inner join `nessus_tags` on `nessus_results`.`tagID` = `nessus_tags`.`tagID` where `nessus_tags`.`unsupported_os` != and nessus_results.scan_end >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP((NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)))
```

However, as you can see in the picture attached ('column exists'), the table do exists. What I am missing?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Best regards!

[column exists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ2JM.png)

Comment: whats table name for Nessus model

Comment: Have you attached table structure of `nessus_tags` table?

Comment: @VishalVarshney `protected $table='nessus_results';`

Comment: if you're doing `where('nessus_tags.unsupported_os', '=', 'true')` what's the point of doing a `select('nessus_tags.unsupported_os')` you know that if it exists it must be `true`.

Comment: @apokryfos: Because there's a null because there are SO that are not supported and they don't have a true in the column. I have the same sturcture for many tables and I do queries like: `!= ''` (if isn't true) and like `= true` (if it has true)

Comment: Have you marked it in your error query??? `nessus_tags`.`unsupported_os` **!= and** nessus_results.scan

Comment: @B.Desai: Yes, same results: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'nessus_tags.unsupported_os' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `nessus_results` inner join `nessus_tags` on `nessus_results`.`tagID` = `nessus_tags`.`tagID` where `nessus_tags`.`unsupported_os` != true and nessus_results.scan_end >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP((NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joining a model with a table is usually a red flag. You should instead make a related model and define a relationship:

```
class Nessus {
       protected $table='nessus_results';
       //model

      public function tags() {
             return $this->hasMany(NessusTag::class, 'tagID');
      }  
}
```

Then you can do:

```
$getUnsupportedOS = Nessus::withCount([ "tags" => function ($q) {
        return $q->where("unsupported_os","=","true"); 
 }])->whereRaw('scan_end >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP((NOW() - INTERVAL '.'1'.' MONTH))')->first();
```

The count is then in: `$getUnsupprtedOS->tags_count`

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and it is giving me this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ']'`

Comment: Thank you, I put the missing bracket in your code. But now it is giving the same error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'nessus_results.unsupported_os' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(DISTINCT nessus_tags.operating_system) as aggregate from `nessus_results` inner join `nessus_tags` on `nessus_results`.`tagID` = `nessus_tags`.`tagID` where nessus_results.scan_end >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP((NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) and `nessus_results`.`unsupported_os` = true)`

Comment: I'm fairly confident that the code I've shared does not result in that query that's failing. I've not even mentioned `operating_system` at all.

Comment: My bad, I corrected my error. Thank you so much for taking of your time. Just to let you know, this is now the error: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::tags()`

Comment: @apokryfos don't you think here you should use whereHas()

Comment: @AjayDeepakKumar possibly. I was trying to match the "count" behaviour in the original OPs question but I'm not sure on what the intended behaviour should be.